# Opera Mini and CSS

Tags: html, css, opera, opera-mini

I'm working on a webapp and I would like to increase the compatibility with the different kinds of mobile browsers.
Opera Mini drives me crazy, I don't understand why a simple code like the following doesn't work properly. All I want is a grey background and a white font. What I get is a grey background and a black font.
Here's the code :

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML Strict 1.0//EN"  
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml;charset=utf-8"/>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./_css/index.css" media="screen"/>
</head>  
<body>  
  <p>blabla</p>  
</body> 
</html>
```

CSS

```
html { margin:0; padding:0; }
body { margin:0; padding:0; font-family:Helvetica; background-color:#BBBBBB; }
p { color:#FFFFFF; }
```

Thanks for any help,
Camille

Comment: So the style sheet gets loaded? It's the correct grey colour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the property media="screen" is the cause of this wrong behaviour.

Try to leave it out or another value: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-types

Comment: Ok, the adhoc media for Opera Mini is `handheld`. Thanks Chris for your answer.

Comment: Opera Mini supports `media=screen` without a problem. However, in case you're in "Mobile view" mode, Opera's small screen rendering view is triggered, or alternatively, CSS with the `handheld` media type is applied. So, if you want your text to look the same in both the normal and mobile view modes, you'll want to include both the `handheld` and `screen` media types.

Comment: Here are the [Opera Mini Specs](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-web-content-authoring-guidelines/) from which @andreasbovens comments come from.